# How to keep values static even when page is refreshed

Tags: .net

I'm working on a movie ticket booking . So when i book a ticket the values are selected  n when i refresh it gets vanish. Can anyone help me so that. If one user has book a seat . Then that seat should be unavailable to other user.

Comment: Did you ever heard of storing data in web application in server and client?

Answer (score 0):

If the user selects a value and that value ain't saved ,when the page gets refreshed,the value dissapears. You have to **save** that value somewhere so that you can refer to that value in the saved location after page gets refreshed.

Use a session variable . Initialize the session variable with an array or a list or a sorted dictionary .Do something like this.

```
 SortedDictionary<int, int> fieldLst = new  SortedDictionary<int, int>
 Session["fieldObjctLst"] = fieldLst;
```

And from the front end, pass the value through an ajax call to the session variable before the page gets refreshed. So you can access the value since the value is in session.

Hope you got the point :)